# iOS 11 beginRefreshing programmatically with large title on navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

In iOS 10, I used to begin refreshing the `UIRefreshControl` (show the refresh control programmatically) programmatically like this:

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: - self.refreshControl.bounds.height), animated: false)
self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
```

But now with iOS 11 that code doesn't work, it does only make a mess with the size of the `UINavigationController` and the `UIRefreshControl` doesn't appear.

How can I begin refreshing programmatically the `UIRefreshControl` (show the refresh control programmatically) using `prefersLargeTitles` from iOS 11?

Comment: As the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol) said, `Because the refresh control is specifically designed for use in a table view that's managed by a table view controller, using it in a different context can result in undefined behavior.`, try to use `UITableViewController` instead.

Comment: any luck so far in getting this solved? I encountered the same problem and every now and then it just works as expected when I run my app in the simulator but then the next time I start the app it messes up the navigation bar again...

Comment: @xxtesaxx I could not solve that. I decided to move all my `UIViewController`s to `UITableViewController`s and it started to behave better.

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

`UIRefreshControl` is meant to be used with `UITableViewController`. Using it on `UITableView`s that aren't in a `UITableViewController` can lead to undefined behaviour.

While it's not always feasible to have your view controller be a subclass of `UITableViewController`, you can always have a `UIViewController` subclass which adds the `UITableViewController` subclass as a child. That way you can use the `UIRefreshControl` and the other niceties that `UITableViewController` provides, while still being able to use `UIViewController` subclasses where needed.